# Cannot access global variable inside class (twython)

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, web-crawler, twython

I'm using the twython module and more particulaty the streamer. All I want to do is count occurences of tweets. But for some reason I cannot access the `ccount` variable inside the class eventhough it's global. Why?

```
class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    btcount=0
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            #print(data['text'])
            ccount+=1
    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print(status_code)



global ccount
ccount=0
stream = MyStreamer(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.statuses.filter(track='something')
```

Additional question is how would I get back the value of my counter after a period if time?

Comment: The `global ccount` goes in the function that modifies `ccount`. Where you have it now doesn't do anything.

Comment: Inside the function it would work indeed. But it defies the purpose since this function is called everytime a new tweet appears the counter will always be 0 or 1